# get value from DataSet table in win forms textBox

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlcommand

I have created a service-based database with one table inside a C# project. Now I want to read some values from that table into my form's text boxes.

For example `field1` from this:

```
select field1 from table where field2 = something;
```

should be displayed in

```
textBox1.Text = table.field1;
```

But I don't know how to execute that SQL-statement.

Comment: read about databinding

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest solution for this scenario according to my perspective, is to use LINQ. When using LINQ, you need to create data model classes from your database before using them. So you need to have an idea about the LINQ queries and the way of generating data model classes based on your DB.

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures) you can find the relevant tutorials on what i have proposed above